# Changing document.readyState property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm adding scripts and styles in `head` tag if they don't exist like this:

```
$(function(){
    var script = CL.addScriptIfMissing('someurl');
    console.log(objectFromScript);
});
```

`addScriptIfMissing` is working correctly.
Then i call objectFromScript from loaded script and it is undefined, because on document load it was not present and it takes time to load. I have one solution:

```
$(function(){
    var script = CL.addScriptIfMissing('someurl');
    script.addEventListener('load', function(){
        console.log(objectFromScript);
    });
});
```

But i need other solution: I want to change document.readyState back to `interactive`. so that `$(document).ready` will be stopped and called second time when script loads

Comment: `$(document).ready()` never was intended to wait for scripts to load, so why would you want that now?

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean? $(document).ready() is not triggered until all scrips are loaded as far as I know

Comment: No. [RTFM!](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): "*The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed*". Nothing about loading assets, that's what `$(window).on('load')` is made for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to reset the state of ready.

```
$.isReady = false;
```

To fire the ready event.

```
$.ready();
```

It's not recommended to change the value of `$.isReady` as it may not work in the future.